# Winter 17 : Lightning strikes again?

Tags: discussion

Are there any major enhancements/ ideas delivered in winter 17 related to Salesforce classic? I saw very few updates related to service cloud but nothing big on sales cloud / general customization for classic.

My org is totally against lightning since it is too premature and is not looking to move this direction any sooner. I looked at the release notes and all I see is lightning/ Process builder based enhancements(could have missed details, hence posting here to see if there are references of classic somewhere in the release notes)

The title screams **"Lightning strikes again"**, the same question pops if Salesforce is slowly departing from classic and focusing more on lightning (or) stabilizing lightning putting classic on hold.

The below update may give some more time for third party devs.

LockerService Critical Update Postponed
LockerService is a powerful security architecture for 
Lightning
 components that was a critical update for Summer 
’
16. 
**This critical update
was scheduled for auto-activation in Winter 
’
17. The auto-activation date has been postponed until Summer 
’
17.**

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter17_release_notes.pdf

Comment: There are plenty of enhancements that are environment agnostic. For instance, the `Composite API`, or the PMD tools that [Robert Sösemann](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/256/robert-s%C3%B6semann) presented on. Also the DX stuff represents a lot of huge changes that have nothing to do with the UI.

Comment: @AdrianLarson what does PMD have to do with the official Salesforce release?  Unless I'm missing something about Static Analysis being incorporated natively in the platform... But I don't see that in the release notes

Comment: Sorry but what is the purpose of this question being in META ? Please try to make this a non-broad question that fits with the style of questions we handle on the main site and post it there.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I wasn't sure if this belonged to META or the SFSE site, posted in meta to be on the safe side.